# Packaging Python scripts with Pandas .read_excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, executable

I would like to have a script that with be executed against multiple dynamic excel files with several data transformation and manipulation. During the process, I have to read another static excel file, which is kind of a reference for me to search through with dynamic ones.

```
import os
import pandas as pd


dir = os.listdir(**path to the dynamic excels to be worked on**)
os.chdir(**path to the dynamic excels to be worked on**)
reference = pd.read_excel('static_excel.xlsx', sheet_name='1')


for file in dir:
   **function that transform and manipulate the data with reference to the static excel file**
```

My question is that I would like to package this script alongside with the static excel as an executable such that I can share this exe file to any other devices that do not have Python installed and the static excel file saved on the local disk. Can you guys think of any practical way to achieve this?

Comment: Use something like pyinstaller and create a single-file executable. Static excel file will need to be shipped alongside. Due to the size of pandas and other libraries the final executable will be circa 300 Mb or more.

Comment: Thanks pavel. If the exe size is going to be so big, then what is the better way to do this? Sorry that I am so new about coding

Comment: If your customers can't run the script natively through Python then there's really no better option. Packaging a distributing standalone executables is pretty poor in case of Python and in many cases if this is what you need on a regular basis, then other languages might suit you better.